# Why won't my model unwrap in blender 2.9?

Tags: uv

[image: 1]

My mesh won't unwrap. It doesn't matter what unwrap option I choose.

Comment: Any more details about how you actually tried it? Did you just press U and Unwrap? or Smart UV unwrap? I don't see any seams on your object. Can you share more info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left you've opened the *Image Editor*, not the *UV Editor*. As far as I know, in the *Image Editor*, you'll only see your UV if you switch it to the *Paint* mode, not *View* mode:

[image]